# Node.js server return error 404 in production

Tags: node.js, api, express, next.js

hope you are good,
I am building my next.js weather app project using openweather API, I set up my proxy server, so the API key won't appear on the client side, it works perfect on my localhost, but when I deploy it on vercel or heroku, it returns error 404, it does the same when requesting directly on postman or browser.

PS: the environment variables are set in my vercel dashboard.
PS: api url example localhost:3000/api/weather?q=london
my **server.js**

```
const next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const needle = require('needle');
const url = require('url');
const cors = require('cors');

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const API_BASE_URL = process.env.API_BASE_URL;
  const API_KEY_NAME = process.env.API_KEY_NAME;
  const API_KEY_VALUE = process.env.API_KEY_VALUE;

  const server = express();

  server.use(
    cors({
      origin: '*',
    })
  );

  server.get(
    '/api/:stat',

    async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const params = new URLSearchParams({
          ...url.parse(req.url, true).slashes,
          ...url.parse(req.url, true).query,
          [API_KEY_NAME]: API_KEY_VALUE,
        });
        const apiRes = await needle(
          'get',
          `${API_BASE_URL}/${req.params.stat}?${params}`
        );
        const data = apiRes.body;
        res.status(200).json(data);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error });
      }
    }
  );

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: What does your call to the server look like?

Comment: localhost:3000/api/weather?q=london

Comment: This is not a CORS issue; dropping the [tag:cors] tag.

Comment: [Custom servers](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in Next.js cannot be deployed on Vercel. Try using [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) instead.

Comment: @juliomalves I deployed it on heroku and the same prob, after some research, I think my server don't start, it might be the script in `package.json` file. I'm trying to fix it